# Geometry of mathematical solution encoded as category theory

Tags: geometry, category-theory

I have a vague question. Essentially the way I visualize mathematics is that let us say we have a given problem. The way that I visualize math solution to given problem is a network of connections whose interaction leads to a particular solution.

That is, let us say we have a solution to a problem is reached when you have certain connections between axioms and implications is reached. This sequence and axioms could be defined in some space where axioms could be taken as variables and the sequence could be taken as morphisms between the axioms.

Just out of curiosity, has something like that been explored before ?

Comment: This is somewhat similar to Boolean algebras? Given any language, one can set up a Boolean algebra consisting of logical formulas of the language, and order these formulas via implication. I don't see how a proof (what you call a "sequence") could be viewed as a morphism of axioms. That doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: It’s not clear what would be a morphism of axioms. I suppose you could take your objects as statements, and morphism $a\to b$ between two statements would be a proof that $b$ follows from $a.$ But not all theories can be written as one statement, because they often contain “axiom schemes,” which are an infinite set of axioms. Also, if a morphism is a proof, there are almost no isomorphisms, because if $a\to b$ and $b\to c$ then $a\to c$ is the concatenation of proofs. On the other hand, if there is only one map $a\to b,$ if there exists a proof, this becomes a category of a pre-order.

Comment: You could also take your objects as sets of statements, with a single morphism $A\to B$ if every element in $B$ has a proof from elements of $A.$ This again is the category of a pre-order, namely $A\leq B$ if  all of $B$ follows from $A.$ This might require infinitely many proofs, if $B$ is infinite. If we restrict to recursively enumerable $A,B$ you might instead require that there is one finite proof which shows everything in $B$ follows from $A.$ Again, this would be a category of a pre-order.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I was thinking also along that lines. Though I feel that this category wouldn't capture most information about the solution.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews (1st comment) multicategories solve this issue.